# How can I make the title and text wrap around this image?

Tags: css, image

I want the text and title to wrap around this time. I've tried `float: left` and `line-height: top`. How can I solve this problem? It should look like this:

[image: Visual Aid]

```css
#verse_div {
  width: 1080px;
  font-family: 'Cambay', sans-serif !important;
  position: relative;
  left: 245px;
  top: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.verse_section {
  width: 293px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 55px;
}

.verse_title {
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #00707C;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.verse_info {
  text-indent: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#verse_1 .verse_info, #verse_2 .verse_info, #verse_3 .verse_info {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.verse_img {
  width: 65px;
  height: 80px;
```

```html
 <div id='verse_div'>
       <!-- #1 -->
       <div class='verse_section'>
         <div class='verse_body' id='verse_1'>
           <span class='verse_title'>  First Title </span> <br>
           <span class='verse_info'>
 <img src='https://www.lds.org/bc/content/shared/content/images/leaders/d-todd-christofferson-large.jpg' class='verse_img'> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed elementum feugiat erat molestie venenatis. Donec a libero ac nisl fringilla interdum. Curabitur massa neque, suscipit id ullamcorper nec, aliquam vel massa. Etiam fringilla leo eu suscipit vehicula. Nulla facilisi. In et convallis diam. Proin vitae est in orci rutrum viverra. In at rhoncus magna. Proin convallis, dolor vitae feugiat sodales, ex velit aliquet ante, ut vehicula dui magna ut elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In eleifend odio tincidunt, finibus velit vitae, viverra velit. Donec finibus semper sem, ut hendrerit diam. Nulla ut purus eget purus tempus aliquam. Duis sodales lectus ut diam bibendum ultrices. Nullam placerat posuere lectus, non luctus diam porttitor non. Integer sed purus lobortis, varius ex in, vestibulum arcu.</span>
         </div>
         
         <div class='verse_body'>
           <span class='verse_title'>Second Title</span> <br>
           <span class='verse_info'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed elementum feugiat erat molestie venenatis. Donec a libero ac nisl fringilla interdum. Curabitur massa neque, suscipit id ullamcorper nec, aliquam vel massa. Etiam fringilla leo eu suscipit vehicula. Nulla facilisi. In et convallis diam. Proin vitae est in orci rutrum viverra. In at rhoncus magna. Proin convallis, dolor vitae feugiat sodales, ex velit aliquet ante, ut vehicula dui magna ut elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In eleifend odio tincidunt, finibus velit vitae, viverra velit. Donec finibus semper sem, ut hendrerit diam. Nulla ut purus eget purus tempus aliquam. Duis sodales lectus ut diam bibendum ultrices. Nullam placerat posuere lectus, non luctus diam porttitor non. Integer sed purus lobortis, varius ex in, vestibulum arcu.
           </span>
         </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: In your code is it possible to put the image above the title ? If yes then just add float:left to your image.

Comment: Should I delete this question? I have an answer and it's turned into spam...

Comment: @FaceCode No, it's now protected so that should stop new users from defacing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#verse_div {
  width: 1080px;
  font-family: 'Cambay', sans-serif !important;
  position: relative;
  left: 245px;
  top: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.verse_section {
  width: 293px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 55px;
}

.verse_title {
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #00707C;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.verse_info {
  text-indent: 25px;
  display: inline;
}

#verse_1 .verse_info, #verse_2 .verse_info, #verse_3 .verse_info {
}

.verse_img {
  width: 65px;
  height: 80px;
```

```html
 <div id='verse_div'>
       <!-- #1 -->
       <div class='verse_section'>
         <div class='verse_body' id='verse_1'><img src='https://www.lds.org/bc/content/shared/content/images/leaders/d-todd-christofferson-large.jpg' class='verse_img'align="left">
           <span class='verse_title'>  First Title </span><br>
           <span class='verse_info'>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed elementum feugiat erat molestie venenatis. Donec a libero ac nisl fringilla interdum. Curabitur massa neque, suscipit id ullamcorper nec, aliquam vel massa. Etiam fringilla leo eu suscipit vehicula. Nulla facilisi. In et convallis diam. Proin vitae est in orci rutrum viverra. In at rhoncus magna. Proin convallis, dolor vitae feugiat sodales, ex velit aliquet ante, ut vehicula dui magna ut elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In eleifend odio tincidunt, finibus velit vitae, viverra velit. Donec finibus semper sem, ut hendrerit diam. Nulla ut purus eget purus tempus aliquam. Duis sodales lectus ut diam bibendum ultrices. Nullam placerat posuere lectus, non luctus diam porttitor non. Integer sed purus lobortis, varius ex in, vestibulum arcu.</span>
         </div>
         
         <div class='verse_body'>
           <span class='verse_title'>Second Title</span> <br>
           <span class='verse_info'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed elementum feugiat erat molestie venenatis. Donec a libero ac nisl fringilla interdum. Curabitur massa neque, suscipit id ullamcorper nec, aliquam vel massa. Etiam fringilla leo eu suscipit vehicula. Nulla facilisi. In et convallis diam. Proin vitae est in orci rutrum viverra. In at rhoncus magna. Proin convallis, dolor vitae feugiat sodales, ex velit aliquet ante, ut vehicula dui magna ut elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In eleifend odio tincidunt, finibus velit vitae, viverra velit. Donec finibus semper sem, ut hendrerit diam. Nulla ut purus eget purus tempus aliquam. Duis sodales lectus ut diam bibendum ultrices. Nullam placerat posuere lectus, non luctus diam porttitor non. Integer sed purus lobortis, varius ex in, vestibulum arcu.
           </span>
         </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```